# What is a controller class in Java SE ?

Tags: java, main-method

Can someone explain the meaning and the position of a controller class in Java ? Why do we need to put the main method there ?

Comment: Can you elaborate more in question ? which controller do you mean here ?

Comment: Can you provide some more context? Where is the term "controller class" mentioned?

Comment: Are you sure that you're not mixing this up with the MVC design pattern commonly used in Web Development?

Answer (score 7):

A controller class is normally a class part of the Model View Controller (MVC) pattern. 
A controller basically controls the flow of the data.

> It controls the data flow into model object and updates the view whenever data changes.

I suggest you read about it:

- [Tutorials point documentation on MVC](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/mvc_pattern.htm)
- [MDN Web docs on MVC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Apps/Fundamentals/Modern_web_app_architecture/MVC_architecture)

Answer (score 0):

The java class which is responsible to handle request and response.
it will return Model  and view Object to DispatcherServlet.
Model: Represents Data in Key Value format.
View: Logical file name.
Controllers: it is loosely coupled with Presentation technology.